# Python Tesseract Struggling to interpret computer text dates

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

So I've been working on a problem to identify a large amount of dates on photo's. So far I've tried using pyTesseract across varying page segmentation methods yet no success. I would have thought that an OCR would have a relatively easy time recognising ASCII text like below however it's struggling.

Here's an output:

https://ocr.space/

```
****** Result for Image/Page 1 ******

22,ü2t201B 11 .Ah,l
```

And here's a python tesseract output:

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(constant,config= '--psm 7')

Out[88]: 'Pe EEE]'
```

Anyone have any suggestions for improvement? I'd be curious to see if anybody could extract the full details from the image - my gut is telling me that the '/' and ':' are messing up the algorithm, so perhaps a method would be to manually remove them from the image array.

Here is the image used:

[image: Example image]

Comment: Try finding contour centers and then segmenting Images based on Contours bounding boxes and passing them Individually, for this you can use opencv

Comment: Yea I was thinking about doing this and using the PSM as single character single per image, but honestly I'm trying to avoid that until a last resort - I'd probably just cut out each character and search through the np.array before doing that.

Answer (score 2):

thanks for the feedback, just thought I'd post my solution that I now have working great!

Two things I've learnt about OCR:

- works significantly better when text is black, background is white.
- works better with more spaces 'gaps' between each characters
- the psm config setting can improve quality.

Here's my code:

```
#timestamp section
def grabStamp(image):  
    #load image and invert black & whites
    image = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    im = np.invert(image)
    #exxtract the time stamp section    
    timeStamp = image[:15,:112]
    #add a boarder & create only binary colors (0,255)
    constant= cv2.copyMakeBorder(timeStamp,10,10,10,10,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=0)
    _, contrasted = cv2.threshold(constant,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)    

    #loop to find colons
    for x in range(0,113):
        if is_slice_in_list(semiColon, np.ndarray.tolist(contrasted[:,x])) == True:
            if np.where(contrasted[:,x]==255)[0][0] == 17:
            #converting back to black pixils        
             contrasted[:,x][ contrasted[:,x] == 255] = 0                

    #loop to find slashes         
    for x in range(0,113):
        if is_slice_in_list(slash, np.ndarray.tolist(contrasted[:,x])) == True: 
            if np.where(contrasted[:,x]==255)[0][0] == 17:
                if is_slice_in_list(slash_, np.ndarray.tolist(contrasted[:,x - 1])) == True:                  
                    contrasted[:,x][ contrasted[:,x] == 255] = 0 
                    contrasted[:,x-1][ contrasted[:,x-1] == 255] = 0 
                    contrasted[:,x+1][ contrasted[:,x+1] == 255] = 0                    
    #invert back
    im = np.invert(contrasted)

    return pytesseract.image_to_string(im,config= '--psm 7')
```

Here's the process running with the alterations to improve accuracy:

```
grabStamp(image)
Out[250]: '22022018 1157 38'
```

here's the process without any adjustment (just invert colours):

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(timeStamp,config= '--psm 7')
Out[254]: 'Prlivd7ihl Rete 3'
```

Original Image:

[image]

Altered Image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Tesseract performs way better in images where text is black on white. So i recommend you to use opencv for that purpose.
Invert the colors of the image and apply guassian blurr to smooth the image. 
**All these methods are easily available on opencv's docs**
Hope this helps.

Comment: Another point is that tesseract expects larger text, so resizing the image (for example four times) combined with inverting the colors will help. You can also play a bit with blurring and thresholding to improve the results even better, but it will be hard to fully eliminate the problem with the slashes which are the cause of trouble here.